# How to get history first different url in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I use plain JavaScript in my project.

I have a basket page where the user can update the basket, which results in a form being submitted and a new entry in `history`.

Now if I call `history.back(-1)` it navigates to the same page.

What is the best practice to find the last different url in the history and navigate to that page?

Comment: I think as a matter of privacy, this isn't possible using just the history API.

Comment: I want to stay on the same domain.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe the history API makes any special cases for same-domain navigation, however since it's your own domain you could always store a "last-visited" cookie/local storage yourself and use that.

Comment: Or even, you can store `visitedHistory` array in `SessionStorage` so you can track all the history of user.